# Dans ou dedans ... Je peux utiliser lequel ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Je veux traduire cette phrase en anglais ci-dessous:

> "[My hands are in places that not a lot of other people's go.](http://www.nj.com/giants/index.ssf/2015/08/which_giants_center_gave_eli_manning_a_smelly_hand.html)"

Mon essai de traduire en français (une mauvaise traduction, je sais) :

« Mes mains sont dedans endroits dont un peu des mains des autres personnes peuvent y aller. »

L'usage exact est-il **dans** ou **dedans**? Je pense qu'on aurait raison si on utilise **dedans** ici en ce contexte parce que je voulais utiliser un adverbe. Et **dans** est réservé aux prépositions.

Comment: Je traduirais cette phrase comme "Mes mains sont dans des endroits où peu de mains d'autres personnes vont"

Comment: @Fatalize Et pourquoi doit-on utiliser *dans* au lieu de *dedans* ici ?

Comment: Parce que ça sonne correct :) Dedans est rarement utilisé de manière générale. Dans quels cas précisément je ne sais pas, attendons une vraie réponse.

Comment: J'ajouterais qu'on ne dit pas "dedans [quelque chose]", on dit "il y a des gants dans cette boîte" ou "voici une boîte, il y a des gants dedans" mais pas "il y a des gants dedans cette boîte".  "dedans" se réfère implicitement à un contenant dont on a parlé auparavant (inversement, on ne dit pas "voici une boîte, il y a des gants dans", il manque quelque chose).

Comment: Quand tu dis « *in places* » *in* est une préposition, en français aussi tu utiliseras une préposition, parce qu'il y a un nom après. On pourrait employer « dedans » en tant que préposition mais c'est désuet, on l'emploie surtout comme adverve quand on a déjà nommé le contenant (voir l'exemple de @Caninonos). Tu peux aussi te dire que dedans veut dire « à l'intérieur » (*inside*).

Comment: De ce que j'ai compris de l'article : "J'ai mis les mains ***dans*** des endroits où peu de gens y mettent les leurs." Caninonos vous a donné les bonnes explications pour choisir entre *dans* et *dedans*.

Comment: @Caninonos +1. Rule of thumb (not sure it is always true): in = _dans_; inside = _dedans_. Does this help you, Cookie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Answer

Here, you have to use "*dans*", there is no other choice.

#### How to know which to use

[Caninonos](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7855/caninonos)'s examples and explanation are perfectly right.

When you use "*dedans*", you already know which container you are speaking of. When you use "*dans*", you *need* to specify that container.

> Voici une boîte, il y a des gants **dedans**.
>   <s>Voici une boîte, il y a des gants **dans**.</s>
>   <s>Il y a des gants **dedans** cette boîte.</s>
>   Il y a des gants **dans** cette boîte.

The difference is about the same as between "in" and "inside" (that is a rule of thumb, though, and I'm not sure if it's always true).

> Here's a box, there are gloves **inside**.
>   There are gloves **in** this box.

In any case, you can *never* say "*dedans quelque chose*".

## Side note: translation advice

Original sentence:

> My hands are in places that not a lot of other people's go.

I would suggest:

> Mes mains sont à des endroits où peu d'autres vont.

- "*à des endroits*": this is almost an idiom, even if the place is enclosed.
- "*peu d'autres (mains) vont*": well, if they're not mine, they're other people's. The meaning is not changed, but the sentence is quite lighter.

As [Random](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7321/random) quite rightly highlighted, though a bit less elegant, the following is closer to the original idea:

> Mes mains sont à des endroits où pas beaucoup d'autres vont.

Comment: I like your translation of the phrase, though would it sound even better to French ears if one could add "...où peu d'autres y vont" (the pronoun *y* )?

Comment: @Cookie You cannot use _y_ in this case, because you have _où_. To use it, you would have to rewrite your sentence: "_Mes mains sont à des endroits. Peu d'autres **y** vont._" ("My hands are in places. Few others go **there**."; yes, it does not sound natural, but for the sake of example...) If you need more information about the use of _y_ with _où_, you can go through [old questions](http://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=y) or ask a new one if none helps you understand.

Comment: If we cannot use *où* and *y* in the same sentence, then does this mean "J'ai mis les mains dans des endroits où peu de gens y mettent les leurs."  (in the comment by @cl-r) is technically gramatically incorrect?

Comment: @Cookie Yes it does. _Où_ and _y_ refer to the same thing: the places your hands are in. This is redundant (and incorrect).

Comment: This is my favorite translation, but shouldn't you change "peu" with "pas beaucoup", since the original sentence uses "not a lot" instead of "few" (it may be a choice of the writer) ? Saying that, it is not very elegant, but maybe we could find something nicer in the same idea...

Comment: @Random You are right. I tend to avoid word-for-word translation and go for the most idiomatic version, but I added a note about this too. I can't think of anything else with the same idea right now, though. Thank you.